# Using a radio button to update a select boxes options

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 radio buttons. If one of them is selected it should fill the select box with new items
http://jsfiddle.net/uuEE2/1/

**Javascript Code**

```
    function Fill(gender)
        {
       var dropdown = document.getElementById("aklasse");

       switch (gender.value){
            case 'm':{
                dropdown.options.length = 0;
                dropdown.options[dropdown.options.length] = new Option("Schüler Jungen(-12 Jahre)","7");
                dropdown.options[dropdown.options.length] = new Option('Jugentliche Jungen (13-15 Jahre)','5');
                dropdown.options[dropdown.options.length] = new Option('Junioren Jungen (16-17 Jahre)','3');
                dropdown.options[dropdown.options.length] = new Option('Erwachsene Herren (18-54 Jahre)','1');
                dropdown.options[dropdown.options.length] = new Option('Senioren Herren','A');
                break;
                    }
              case 'w':
              {
                dropdown.options.length = 0;
                dropdown.options[dropdown.options.length] = new Option('Schüler Mädchen (-12 Jahre)','8');
                dropdown.options[dropdown.options.length] = new Option('Jugentliche Mädchen (13-15 Jahre)','6');
                dropdown.options[dropdown.options.length] = new Option('Junioren Mädchen (16-17 Jahre)','4');
                dropdown.options[dropdown.options.length] = new Option('Erwachsene Damen (18-54 Jahre)','2');
                dropdown.options[dropdown.options.length] = new Option('Senioren Damen','B');
                break;
              }
           }
       }
```

**HTML-Code**

```
     <tr>
        <td align="right">Geschlecht: </td>
        <td align="left">männlich<input name="gender" type="radio" value="m" id="mgender" onclick="Fill(this);"/>
        <input name="gender" type="radio" value="w" onclick="Fill(this);"/> weiblich
        </td>
        <td>*</td>
    </tr>

<tr>
        <td align="right">Altersklasse: </td>
        <td align="left"><select name="altersklasse" id="aklasse" size="1">
        <option value="00">Select  First</option>   
        </select></td>
    </tr>
```

**PHP Code**

```
    <?php
if(empty($_POST['aklasse']))
$aklasse = "";
else
$aklasse = $_POST['aklasse'];
    if($aklasse =="")
        echo "Altersklasse wurde nicht ausgewählt<br>";
    else
    {
    switch ($gender)
        {
        case "m":
            if(($aklasse == "8") || ($aklasse == "6") || ($aklasse == "4") || ($aklasse == "2") || ($aklasse == "B"))
                echo "Ihre Angabe ist ungültig. Geschlecht und Altersklasse müssen übereinstimmen!"; 
            elseif(($aklasse == "7") && (alter($geb) > 12))
                echo "Alter und Altersklasse müssen übereinstimmen";
            elseif(($aklasse == "5") && ((alter($geb) < 13) ||(alter($geb) > 15)))
                echo "Alter und Altersklasse müssen übereinstimmen";
            elseif(($aklasse == "3") && ((alter($geb) < 16) ||(alter($geb) > 17)))
                echo "Alter und Altersklasse müssen übereinstimmen";
            elseif(($aklasse == "1") && ((alter($geb) < 18) ||(alter($geb) > 54)))
                echo "Alter und Altersklasse müssen übereinstimmen";
            elseif(($aklasse == "A") && (alter($geb) < 54))
                echo "Alter und Altersklasse müssen übereinstimmen";
            else
                echo "Altersklasse: " .$aklasse ."<br>";                        
            break;

        case "w":
            if(($aklasse == "7") || ($aklasse == "5") || ($aklasse == "3") || ($aklasse == "1") || ($aklasse == "A"))
                echo "Ihre Angabe ist ungültig. Geschlecht und Altersklasse müssen übereinstimmen!";
            elseif(($aklasse == "8") && (alter($geb) > 12))
                echo "Alter und Altersklasse müssen übereinstimmen";
            elseif(($aklasse == "6") && ((alter($geb) < 13) ||(alter($geb) > 15)))
                echo "Alter und Altersklasse müssen übereinstimmen";
            elseif(($aklasse == "4") && ((alter($geb) < 16) ||(alter($geb) > 17)))
                echo "Alter und Altersklasse müssen übereinstimmen";
            elseif(($aklasse == "2") && ((alter($geb) < 18) ||(alter($geb) > 54)))
                echo "Alter und Altersklasse müssen übereinstimmen";
            elseif(($aklasse == "B") && (alter($geb) < 54))
                echo "Alter und Altersklasse müssen übereinstimmen";
            else 
                echo "Altersklasse: " .$aklasse ."<br>";
            break;          
        }
    }   
    ?>
```

But with this code I cant get the value(in php) after I submit. I always get the message that nothing was selected. Without reducing the select box (but i dont want like this) it works fine but I want with like this: if i check the  radiobutton with the value m(male) : fill the select box with new array. or with the value w(female): again filled with another list. Hope u guys understood what i wanted to know (My English isnt the best)

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for the same ?

Comment: Well, the problem may be in your PHP code, but you don't show it to us so it's hard to tell...

Comment: added a jsfiddle there were no php place so i put my code into css

Comment: Given that you already know the gender (from the radio-input), why are you using different values to denote the gender *again* in the select? Why not just use the gender (which you already know) and the age-range, so that you don't have to use different values for the same age-range to denote male/female?

Comment: i dont know if i understood u or not but the value for the text for example: text: Schüler Jungen(-12 Jahre)", -> value "7" this has to be the value every text has a different value because of the teacher he told us this text has to have this value and so on

Comment: Really? That seems ridiculously redundant. :(

Comment: I think the reason for this is because if u select Schüler Jungen(-12 Jahre) u get after submitting the value of the text so u know which one was selected by the user.. anyway someone got a solution how i can get the value from the text after submitting ?

Comment: It works now but anyone knows how i can do the same function with arrays:

        var male_class = new Array(
   new Array("Schüler Jungen(-12 Jahre)", "7"),
   new Array("Jugentliche Jungen (13-15 Jahre)", "5");

  var female_class = new Array(
   new Array("Schüler Mädchen (-12 Jahre)", "8"),
   new Array("Senioren Damen", "B"));
a school mate did this with those 2 arrays and i think he used for or something i couldnt see it but he doesnt want to tell anyone how he did this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken...    shouldn't this line:

```
$aklasse = $_POST['aklasse'];
```

Be this?

```
$aklasse = $_POST['altersklasse'];
```

The `name` is used to get values from the POST, not the element's ID tag.

Comment: It works now but anyone knows how i can do the same function with arrays:

        var male_class = new Array(
   new Array("Schüler Jungen(-12 Jahre)", "7"),
   new Array("Jugentliche Jungen (13-15 Jahre)", "5");

  var female_class = new Array(
   new Array("Schüler Mädchen (-12 Jahre)", "8"),
   new Array("Senioren Damen", "B"));
a school mate did this with those 2 arrays and i think he used for or something i couldnt see it but he doesnt want to tell anyone how he did this